# Java Appengine: How to store a transformed image back to blobstore

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm able to

-Upload an image to the blobstore

-Transform this image (in my case rescale it)

But I don't seem to be able to find out how I can store the transformed image back to Blobstore.

Any ideas?

BR,

Comment: If you just need to resize an image, a much simpler approach would be to use dynamic resizing and cropping with [getServingUrl](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesService#getServingUrl(com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey))

Comment: True but I need multiple transformations so I am worried that it will be too slow. Also storage cost and processing cost will go up. Would storing it into a blob via normal data store be advisable? The 1 meg limit is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is currently only an experimental feature. You can create a "file" using [createNewBlobFile](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/files/FileService#createNewBlobFile%28java.lang.String%29).

Get more information here: [Writing Files to the Blobstore (Experimental)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore).

Comment: Experimental sounds not ready for production.  Any experience yet?

Comment: No, but do you have a choice? Usually even the experimental features are quite stable. Another option would be, to upload the changed image through an HTTP POST request. I wouldn't do that unless I had no other choice.